# Admin. Register model in other app administration

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-permissions

In admin panel I'm looking to having all user related models in one `app administration`, including Group and Permission models, which are by default included in `Authentication and authorization` app.

**Is there a way of changing default render place of model in admin?**

Also, I'm understand that I can inherit a Group class to make my own, but I'd like to avoid that.

I've tried making custom `ModelAdmin` and to ugregister and register with it, but it's still in `Authentication and authorization`.

My code right now (as starting point):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('permissions',)

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Researched a bit and found this solution, IDK if there is a better one, but this works.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .models import User

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('permissions',)


class GroupNewMeta:
    proxy = True
    app_label = User._meta.app_label


admin.site.unregister(Group)
group_model = type("Group", (Group,), {'__module__': '', 'Meta': GroupNewMeta})
admin.site.register(group_model, GroupAdmin)
```

In `type("Group", (Group,), {'__module__': '', 'Meta': GroupNewMeta})` arguments are:

1. model name in admin panel
2. tuple with model class
3. forced `**options` kwargs of `admin.site.register` method